# What does "freedom" mean in the RankNet paper?

Tags: ranking, learning-to-rank

In the RankNet (Learning to Rank using Gradient Descent) paper, paragraph 3.1, it said

> given the consistency requirements, how much freedom is there to choose the pairwise probabilities?

What does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

I think they're talking about the freedom of deciding the labels for the posterior probabilities. The constraint rises from the fact that the probability model depends on distances between scores, and thus needs to satisfy some consistency when combining probabilities.
An example of this consistency is shown through consecutive ranks: if A->B and B->C how must the probability between A and C act? this is shown in their figure where confidence builds and propagates.
So given that you must satisfy some consistency, how much freedom do you have in choosing the posterior labels? This is addressed in their following theorem where they show that for a set of M documents you can choose M-1 different posteriors and with them define every pairwise probability uniquely if satisfying the requirement.